# pg-promise search for VARCHAR value in an array

Tags: pg-promise

I have a table that has a column `tagging_contexts` with a type of `VARCHAR[]`
If I query the column in the command line I get the following output:

```
select tagging_contexts FROM my_table where id=92;
  tagging_contexts  
--------------------
 {"User Interface"}
(1 row)
```

I would like to select all from any row that has the value "User Interface" in the tagging_contexts column array. My query however, is not working:

```
let context = "User Interface";
return db.any('SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE $1 = ANY ($/tagging_contexts:csv/)', context)
...
```

My expected output would be to get the row with the ID of 92, any help is appreciated!

Comment: You cannot use `Named Parameters` and `Index Variables` in the query at the same time. The type is inferred from what you are passing in as values. If it is an object, then you only use `Named Parameters`, and if it is an array of values - only the `Index Variables`.

Comment: Sorry for not understanding, I tried db.any('SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE $1 = ANY tagging_contexts', context) but that does not work as well (I'm not sure how to write the query).

Comment: I am trying to get (psuedo code) "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 'User Interface' IS IN THE ARRAY IN THE tagging_contexts column, sorry if that was not clear.